# File Download hit counter PHP, MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm new to programming and Web Development all together. So please take it easy on me.

Right. My question is I have a file that users will download from the website. What I want to do is create a function that keeps track of the amount of times it has been downloaded. I have no problem in display the current count.

How can I update the Mysql database when a new click has been made?

So this is my link:

```
<a href="downloads/<?php echo $website->temp_link ?>"> Download </a>
```

This is my counter (retrieves amount of times it has been downloaded):

```
<h6 class="downloaded-count text-center"> Downloaded: <?php echo file_counter() ?></h6>
```

File counter:

```
function file_counter(){
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $query = $db->query("SELECT temp_downloads FROM templates");
    if(@$query->count()){
        foreach($query->results() as $query_run){
            $valid_count = $query_run->temp_downloads;
        }
    } return $valid_count;
}
```

Is there a way I could use html form with post method? and then create a function file_counter_inc() which receives form name or button name ? Or maybe use Javascript onclick method? which receives php function? P.s Don't know if the javascript thing would work

---

**Update**

OK I figured out how to increment the Mysql field after user clicks the button. Another proble m arise.... This is what I did. Looking at bellow code. How can I force a download now? I can't place the file into the form since the method now is PHP_SELF. So I cant place another method there.

This is my html now.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Download" name="download_counter">
</form>
<p class="text-center"> Downloaded: <?php echo file_counter() ?> </p>
```

This is file_counter_inc() method:

```
function file_counter_inc($tempID){
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $query = $db->query("UPDATE templates SET temp_downloads = temp_downloads + 1 WHERE temp_id = '{$tempID}'");
}
```

Php uses Post method to know whether button was clicked.

```
if( isset($_POST['download_counter']))
{
file_counter_inc($website->temp_id);

}
```

How can I force a download after the file_counter_inc() method has been executed?

Comment: To update the DB and increase the counter by one, you'd do something like `UPDATE table SET column=column +1` and maybe add a `WHERE` clause which would probably be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download hit counter PHP, MYSQL possibly some Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372884/download-hit-counter-php-mysql-possibly-some-javascript)

Comment: @David that post was posted by myself... It was not answered

Comment: @Fred-ii- But how will php know when a button has been clicked? How will it know when to update it?

Comment: @TonyS: The point is, please don't re-post the same question.  You can draw attention to the existing post by editing/improving the question, which can include updating it with ongoing efforts and descriptions of how those efforts aren't quite working.  Repeating the same question a day later isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Just add it in your function. You can use [`multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for my ignorance but I still dont understand how this might work. I read online about multi_query() but not sure how could I imprement it.

Comment: You might get way with adding this under your existing query `$query .= $db->query("UPDATE table SET column=column +1");` @TonyS

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `PHP` function to handle the download requests, and increment the counter inside the function, for example, create `download.php` and pass the requested file as a GET parameter:

```
file_counter_inc();     // <-- The increment happens here

$file_url = $_GET['file_url'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"MyFile\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Then you output the download link like this:

```
<a href="download.php?file_url=downloads/<?php echo $website->temp_link ?>"> Download </a>
```

Comment: How could I achieve this with $_POST ? staying on the same page?

Comment: If it's a download most (all?) browsers will load the page, realize it's a file, and download it instead of showing it as a page. Meaning, you'll stay on the page you are currently on.